# Difference between 2 GoPro Hero Cameras

Tags: gopro, camera-identification

I know nothing of GoPro and know I can afford a second hand "GoPro Hero".

I know I can't afford a numbered one (e.g. GoPro Hero 3 / 4 / 5).

Thus I am looking at those without a number and only shows GoPro Hero.

There are however from what I see, at least 2 versions of these (unnumbered) GoPro Heros.
. Number 1:
[image]
[image]

Update : [Its the HD Hero 1080 (HD Hero Naked)](http://cbcdn2.gp-static.com/uploads/product_manual/file/34/HD-HERO-UM-ENG-110110.pdf)

Number 2:

[image]
[image]

Update : Its the [Hero](http://cbcdn2.gp-static.com/uploads/product_manual/file/278/UM_HERO_ENG_REVB_WEB.pdf) and its housing is integrated

Questions:

1. I suspect there is the original GoPro Hero HD Original 2012 and a budget 2014 one - is this correct?
2. Is it the  GoPro Hero HD Original 2012 in Number 1 in the pictures?
3. Is it the same camera as the image in Number 2?
4. I couldn't get a picture of the back of Number 2, but I've seen that it some do not have the Resolutions at the back - does this mean they are totally different cameras with different specs?
5. It looks like some of the GoPro Hero's (not numbered ones) can take Wifi - and others not. If I am on the right track that there are 2 different GoPro Heros- am I correct that the 2014 budget one cannot take Wifi, but the Original HD 2012 one can take Wifi?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first camera is the GoPro HD Hero (2009). It physically looks identical to the GoPro Hero 960 (2010), but it can capture 1080p and had a higher MSRP.

The second camera could be a Hero 3 (2012), 3+ (2013), or 4 (2014) - with the [blackout housing](https://shop.gopro.com/accessories-2/blackout-housing/AHBSH-401.html).  I can't tell anything more from the pictures, but it's at least a Hero 3.

Comment: Hi dpollitt, thanks for reply. The second camera does not have a number - it just states "GoPro" as well, where all GoPro 3's that  I've seen show the "GoPro 3" in the bottom right corner (just confirmed with seller its not GoPro3)

Comment: Hi dpollitt, i followed the link to the blackout housing, and was able to go through some of the product manuals and identify the products, thanks